# Positioning div at the bottom of the page

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am developing a website where the menu it should be the end of the page. Besides the menu, another div with two images should also sit at the bottom of the page.

Follow [the link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/85unG/34/) to the complete source code of the page;

In red, the menu should be aligned at the bottom of the page, aligned to the center of div#leftcontent.

In the div#blue social-networks must be aligned at the bottom of the page, aligned to the center of the div#nav.

When I say bottom, I mean right at the end of the page.

Comment: You forgot to add the link to the sourcecode. It's not in your questionsource under -edit- so you must have forgotten it. Can you add it?

Comment: I add the link.
Here again:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/85unG/34/

Answer (score 0):

If you mean not statically positioned, but just naturally occurring at the bottom of the page even when the sidebar content causes the page to exceed beyond the main content under which the bottom nav occurs, then you are out of luck using divs. This is one of CSS 2.1's major shortcomings.

You are left with two options:

- Use a table for the basic layout
- Use javascript to dynamically position the div based on the length of the sidebar

It's up to which you want to choose, but the javascript option will not work for people with javascript disabled, such as older mobile browsers.

Comment: I would just use CSS.
I believe it's possible, I just want to align the div to the bottom of the body